# ui-grid field returning array

Tags: angularjs, filter, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gxaY.png)

Hi,
I need to filter out some company name based on location('SB' or 'CO'). So i used custom filter in ui-grid. It returns the entire value of each key and only when it completes the mapping. I have attached the output. 
Plunker code demo: [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/howRrsUcewE95dYQvGV7?p=preview)
Used: Angular - v1.4.2
      ui-grid - v3.0.7

```
    application.controller('ApplicationController', ['$scope', 'uiGridConstants', 'ApplicationService',
        function ($scope, uiGridConstants, ApplicationService) {
            $scope.message = "Welcome";
            $scope.gridOptions = {
                showGridFooter: true,
                showColumnFooter: true,
                enableFiltering: true
            };
            $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
                {
                    name: 'company',
                    field: 'company',
                    filterHeaderTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-filter-container" ng-repeat="colFilter in col.filters"><div my-custom-dropdown></div></div>',
                    filter: {
                        term: '',
                        options: [{ id: 'CO', value: 'Navy' }, { id: 'CO', value: 'Army' }, { id: 'SB', value: 'Hp' }]
                    },
                    cellFilter: 'mapCompany'
                }
            ];
            ApplicationService.getData(function (response) {
                if (response) {
                    $scope.gridOptions.data = response.data;
                    response.data.forEach(function addDates(row, index) {
                        var companyName = row.company;
                        if (companyName === 'Navy')
                            row.company = 'CO';
                        else if (companyName === 'Army')
                            row.company = 'CO';
                        else if (companyName === 'Hp')
                            row.company = 'SB';
                    });
                }
                else {
                    $scope.gridOptions.data = null;
                }
            });
        }
    ])
    .filter('mapCompany', function () {
            var genderHash = {
                'CO': ['Navy'],
                'CO': ['Army'],
                'SB': ['Hp']
            };
            return function (input) {
                if (!input) {

                    return '';
                }
                else {
                    return genderHash[input];
                }
            };
        })
     .directive('myCustomDropdown', function () {
            return {
                template: '<input ng-model="colFilter.term" >'
            };
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        filter: {
                condition: function(searchTerm,cellValue) {
                  if( !searchTerm || searchTerm === '') {
                    return true;
                  }

                  if(searchTerm === 'CO') {
                    if(cellValue === 'Navy' || cellValue === 'Army') {
                     return true; 
                    }
                  }
                  if(searchTerm === 'SB') {
                    if(cellValue === 'Hp') {
                     return true; 
                    }
                  }
                  return false;
                }
              }
```

I should have used filter parameter in gridOptions instead of cellFilter with Hashmap

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

```
var genderHash = {
            'CO': ['Navy'],
            'CO': ['Army'],
            'SB': ['Hp']
        };
```

change to:

```
var genderHash = {
            'CO': 'Navy',
            'CO': 'Army',
            'SB': 'Hp'
        };
```

**Also keep in mind you created map with the same key `"CO"`**

Comment: Your answer solved my question partially. But still 'Army' alone is not visible in the front-end. May be it's because of the assignment row.company = 'CO' inside the loop(foreach).

Comment: @NirmalBalajiPackirisamy could you post demo in plunker?

Comment: It will take me some time to post demo in Plunker.

Comment: I used same key for two different values because in my app when the user searches for 'CO' the filtered output should contain both 'Navy' and 'Army'. (Many to one mapping).

Comment: Here is the plunker code demo that you asked for:
[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/howRrsUcewE95dYQvGV7?p=preview)